# Async instead of then() for server.listen()

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, apollo

This is how a apollo server is started:

```
server.listen(port).then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`Server ready at ${url}`)
})
```

I would like to use the async/await synthax. So I tried to do - which is wrong:

```
server.listen(port, async ({ url }) => {
  await anyFunction()
  console.log(`Server ready at ${url}`)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async-await` behaves a similar way as of `.then()` chain, `await` waits for promise to get resolved or rejected and then continue process just like `.then()` continue on promise resolve and `.catch()` on promise reject.

`await` returns same result that `.then()` get on promise resolve, i.e:

```
foo().then( function(result){}); // got result here
result = await foo(); // will get same result here too as in above function.
```

similarly `catch(err)` in `try-catch` gets same error as by `.catch( function(err) {})` in `.then()-.catch()`.

Learn more about [async-await here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [here](https://javascript.info/async-await).

To convert your .then() to async-await just do this:

```
(async function () {
    try {
        const { url } = await server.listen(port);
        console.log(`Server ready at ${url}`);
    } catch(e) {
        // handle errors
    }
})();      // This is [IIFE][3]. In this case it's better to have IIFE then regular function, as functions needed to be called.
```

async-await as a function:

```
async function startServer() {
    try {
        const { url } = await server.listen(port);
        console.log(`Server ready at ${url}`);
    } catch(e) {
        // handle errors
    }
}

startServer();    // Not an IIFE
```

Comment: Didn't know about IIFE.

Comment: An IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is a JavaScript function that runs as soon as it is defined. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Answer (score 2):

You would have to make the function the whole code block is *contained in* `async`. Then, just as how `.then` is being called on `server.listen`, you would `await server.listen(...` instead:

```
async function foo() {
  // ...
  const { url } = await server.listen(port);
  console.log(`Server ready at ${url}`);
}
```

Make sure to catch errors, too - either in the consumer of `foo`:

```
foo()
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle errors
  });
```

or in a `catch` block inside `foo`:

```
async function foo() {
  try {
    const { url } = await server.listen(port);
    console.log(`Server ready at ${url}`);
  } catch(e) {
    // handle errors
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to `await` the promise *returned*, don't fall back to callback style:

```
 (async function () {
    const url = await server.listen(port);
    console.log(`Server listening at "${url}"`);
 })();
```